# Which complete graphs have an Euler tour? Which of the complete graphs have an Euler trail?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

I think the complete graphs with odd vertices would be Euler tours, because they are connected and each vertex has even valency. I'm having trouble thinking through Euler trails and complete graphs, wouldn't every graph with an Euler tour also have an Euler trail?

Comment: A graph has an Euler trail but no Euler circuit iff it has exactly two vertices of odd degree, in which case every Euler trail has those vertices as endpoints. This affects $K_n$ for only one value of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You’re welcome!